# How to retrieve data that are not in common

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with a "tag" tree and "user" tree. Each user has some tags (that are named preferences in this case) associated. The database structure it's like that:

[image]

I would like to show in a list, for a determined user, all the preferences that the user don't have.

```
Example: 
Tags: 1, 2, 3, 4
User has 1,3 
I want to show in a list, 2 and 4!
```

I have a code that show correctly all the preferences/tags that the user has, but I don't know how to show a list of what the user don't have!

This is my code that show the common preferences (that works perfectly)

```
  showUserPreferences(){

   let userTag = [];
   var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ this.email+'/preferenze/') 
   var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('/tag/');
   ref.once('value', function(preferenze){ 
     preferenze.forEach(function(singolaPref){
       ref1.once('value', function(tags){ 
        tags.forEach(function (singoloTag){ 
           if(singolaPref.key == singoloTag.key){ 

           userTag.push(singolaPref.child("nome").val()) 
           }
           return false;
         })
       })
       return false;
     })

   }).then(a=>{
       this.tags = userTag;
     }) 
  }
```

I hope I have explained my problem correctly. If you need more code or other details, ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you retrieve data that are in common?

Comment: With the code pasted in my question. I check if an item of tag tree it's into user's preferences tree my the key of the tag

Comment: I'd load the tags from the user's preferences first. Then load the tags and filter those out, which are already in the users preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I might as well submit an answer with a rough code example.

The idea is that you load both snapshots (the `preferenze` and the `tag` collection). You could then e.g. save the `preferenze` in a map for easy lookup. And then use this map when iterating over the tags.

```
showMissingPreferences() { 
    var preferencesRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ this.email+'/preferenze/') 
    var tagsRef = firebase.database().ref('/tag/');

    preferencesRef.once('value')
        .then(userPrefSnap => {

            // Save the user's tags in a map for lookup.
            let userPrefMap: { [key: string]: boolean } = {}
            userPrefSnap.forEach(userTagSnap => {
                userPrefMap[userTagSnap.key] = true
            })

            return tagsRef.once('value')
                .then((tagsSnap) => {
                    let missingTags = []
                    tagsSnap.forEach(tagSnap => {
                        // Only push the tag if it's not in the map.
                        if(!userPrefMap[tagSnap.key]) {
                            missingTags.push(tagSnap.child("nome").val())
                        }
                    })
                    return missingTags
                })
        })
        .then(missingTags => {
            this.tags = missingTags
        })
}
```

I didn't run or test the code so there might be errors. But I hope you get the idea!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried your code and unfortunately this returns me all the tags that are into the tag tree. I'm trying to understand this and understand why it doesn't returns the missing tags but all of them.

Comment: I found the "error"! it's if(!userPrefMap[tagSnap.key]) not if(!userPrefMap[tagsSnap.key]) :D 
thank you sososoo much :D